# jquery file uplaod form plugin response issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I find form plugin interesting and i want to know that how i can embed ajax response in html text area in asp.net mvc 2. any idea?

Here is the link of that control
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the success callback which will be invoked once the AJAX request succeeds and update the contents of your textarea:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(result) {
        $('#txtArea').val(result);
    }
});
```